# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).once is not a function in bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have installed bootstrap theme for building responsive theme then I installed jquery_update module as documentation in theme project and everything seems ok expect below js error appears in inspect elements console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).once is not a function in
>   bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?o5l669

Any one please can help me?
this is the `bootstrap.js`:

```
/**
 * @file
 * bootstrap.js
 *
 * Provides general enhancements and fixes to Bootstrap's JS files.
 */

var Drupal = Drupal || {};

(function($, Drupal){
  "use strict";

  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrap = {
    attach: function(context) {
      // Provide some Bootstrap tab/Drupal integration.
      $(context).find('.tabbable').once('bootstrap-tabs', function () {
        var $wrapper = $(this);
        var $tabs = $wrapper.find('.nav-tabs');
        var $content = $wrapper.find('.tab-content');
        var borderRadius = parseInt($content.css('borderBottomRightRadius'), 10);
        var bootstrapTabResize = function() {
          if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left') || $wrapper.hasClass('tabs-right')) {
            $content.css('min-height', $tabs.outerHeight());
          }
        };
        // Add min-height on content for left and right tabs.
        bootstrapTabResize();
        // Detect tab switch.
        if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left') || $wrapper.hasClass('tabs-right')) {
          $tabs.on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
            bootstrapTabResize();
            if ($wrapper.hasClass('tabs-left')) {
              if ($(e.target).parent().is(':first-child')) {
                $content.css('borderTopLeftRadius', '0');
              }
              else {
                $content.css('borderTopLeftRadius', borderRadius + 'px');
              }
            }
            else {
              if ($(e.target).parent().is(':first-child')) {
                $content.css('borderTopRightRadius', '0');
              }
              else {
                $content.css('borderTopRightRadius', borderRadius + 'px');
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  /**
   * Bootstrap Popovers.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapPopovers = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings.bootstrap && settings.bootstrap.popoverEnabled) {
        var elements = $(context).find('[data-toggle="popover"]').toArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          var $element = $(elements[i]);
          var options = $.extend(true, {}, settings.bootstrap.popoverOptions, $element.data());
          $element.popover(options);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  /**
   * Bootstrap Tooltips.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapTooltips = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings.bootstrap && settings.bootstrap.tooltipEnabled) {
        var elements = $(context).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').toArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          var $element = $(elements[i]);
          var options = $.extend(true, {}, settings.bootstrap.tooltipOptions, $element.data());
          $element.tooltip(options);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  /**
   * Anchor fixes.
   */
  var $scrollableElement = $();
  Drupal.behaviors.bootstrapAnchors = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var i, elements = ['html', 'body'];
      if (!$scrollableElement.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          var $element = $(elements[i]);
          if ($element.scrollTop() > 0) {
            $scrollableElement = $element;
            break;
          }
          else {
            $element.scrollTop(1);
            if ($element.scrollTop() > 0) {
              $element.scrollTop(0);
              $scrollableElement = $element;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!settings.bootstrap || !settings.bootstrap.anchorsFix) {
        return;
      }
      var anchors = $(context).find('a').toArray();
      for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        if (!anchors[i].scrollTo) {
          this.bootstrapAnchor(anchors[i]);
        }
      }
      $scrollableElement.once('bootstrap-anchors', function () {
        $scrollableElement.on('click.bootstrap-anchors', 'a[href*="#"]:not([data-toggle],[data-target])', function(e) {
          this.scrollTo(e);
        });
      });
    },
    bootstrapAnchor: function (element) {
      element.validAnchor = element.nodeName === 'A' && (location.hostname === element.hostname || !element.hostname) && element.hash.replace(/#/,'').length;
      element.scrollTo = function(event) {
        var attr = 'id';
        var $target = $(element.hash);
        if (!$target.length) {
          attr = 'name';
          $target = $('[name="' + element.hash.replace('#', '') + '"');
        }
        var offset = $target.offset().top - parseInt($scrollableElement.css('paddingTop'), 10) - parseInt($scrollableElement.css('marginTop'), 10);
        if (this.validAnchor && $target.length && offset > 0) {
          if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          var $fakeAnchor = $('<div/>')
            .addClass('element-invisible')
            .attr(attr, $target.attr(attr))
            .css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: offset + 'px',
              zIndex: -1000
            })
            .appendTo(document);
          $target.removeAttr(attr);
          var complete = function () {
            location.hash = element.hash;
            $fakeAnchor.remove();
            $target.attr(attr, element.hash.replace('#', ''));
          };
          if (Drupal.settings.bootstrap.anchorsSmoothScrolling) {
            $scrollableElement.animate({ scrollTop: offset, avoidTransforms: true }, 400, complete);
          }
          else {
            $scrollableElement.scrollTop(offset);
            complete();
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: can u check the jQuery version in your site ? In case the version still shows less than requirement (1.9.0) goto the jquery_update config page select the version you want and save ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1996308

Comment: There is no jQuery `once` method so is the file that adds it missing?

Comment: my jquery version in site is 1.10

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and my solution is exclude `bootstrap.js` on my custom theme.

also [you can alter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2149561#15)  `bootstrap.js`

Maybe The problem is because of two version ov jquery load on your page, inspect your javascript and  if there is two version of jquery, let one exist and remove another.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are 2 jquery files (core, theme). I removed it from theme. it works perfectly fine.